# dynamodb client silently failing and then timing out

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, circleci, aws-sdk-js, amazon-dynamodb-local

I'm trying to run tests against [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html) in CircleCI and they are silently failing and eventually timing out. There are no errors reported by the [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html). What could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simple, but tough to find. You need to make sure to define the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_REGION`. Or, you can define them in your options when calling `new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()`.

For CircleCI, just include something like:

```
      - image: circleci/node:10-browsers
        environment:
          # The AWS vars are required or else the DynamoDB client will silently fail
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: FOO
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: FOO
          AWS_REGION: FOO
```

Comment: At the bottom of each AWS documentation page is a link to open a ticket for them to improve that page in the docs. Can you please submit one for this and what the change is so other benefit?

Comment: var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-2'});
    AWS.config.update({access_key_id: 'xxxx'});
    AWS.config.update({secret_access_key: 'yyyy'});